# Generate and store random variables

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create some dynamic user defined variables, use them within http requests in JMETER and also save them to file. Basically I'm testing the creation of accounts and would like to save the accounts I've created.

The problem is when I use **User Defined Variables** and then set the values as below, it only generated the random strings **once** and in subsequent loops it uses the same data and fails as email already exists:

```
FIRSTNAME1      Bob${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}
LASTNAME1       Surname${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}
EMAIL1          Bob${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@emailaddres.com
```

To save this to file I use:

```
name1 = vars.get("EMAIL1");
name2 = vars.get("FIRSTNAME1");
name3 = vars.get("LASTNAME1");

f = new FileOutputStream("C://test/Register_new_user_Jmeter.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
p.println(name1 + "," + name2 + "," + name3);
f.close(
```

How do I set this up so I can generate random strings, use them to create new accounts and also save the info to file? Thanks

Comment: You say the code is in a loop, however I do not see a loop. Perhaps you should paste the entire code. From what is shown, name1,2 and 3 are only initialized once. If you want the names generated to be different each time, you can use the same variables and then reassign their values with your function with each iteration n the body of your "loop"

Comment: I meant there is a JMeter thread and I set the loop there. The code snippet above is in a beanshell processor within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)  are used for defining once (static) variables, use other component, especially User Parameters for dynamic values.

> If a runtime element such as a User Parameters Pre-Processor or Regular Expression Extractor defines a variable with the same name as one of the UDV variables, then this will replace the initial value, and all other test elements in the thread will see the updated value.

[User Parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters)  are creating variables same as User Defined Variable, but can override pervious values

> If there are more threads than values, the values get re-used. For example, this can be used to assign a distinct user id to be used by each thread. User variables can be referenced in any field of any JMeter Component.

Comment: Oh nicely done! Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.